# shows blank screen when click on button in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6.3

I have added a UIBarButtonItem in the main screen and created a **b.xib, b.h and b.m** files for it. when i click on the button it should open the respected screen but it doesn't and opens blank screen.

I am very new to iOS programming....

below is the code in `A.m` file where I added button and when click on it it should open `b.xib`.

```
UIBarButtonItem *bButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"B"
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(openB:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = bButton;
bButton.TintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.31 blue:0.56 alpha:1.0];
[bButton release];

- (void)openB:(id)sender {
BViewController *b = [[BViewController alloc] init];
// ttod.defViewC = self; //Bookmarks from the definition view
[self presentModalViewController:b animated:YES];
[b release];
}
```

any idea...how can i make it work perfectly...

Comment: check here...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621619/presentviewcontroller-shows-black-page

Comment: you have to enter `nib` name

Comment: Filenames **a**, **b** .... my head hurts. Firstly, instead of `presentModalViewController:` use `presentViewController:animated:` since the former was deprecated versions ago. You are not using ARC? Finally, when it's a XIB file you want to load, use `initWithNibName:` instead of `init`.

Answer (score 2):

```
BViewController *b = [[BViewController alloc] init];
```

If you create a nib for the ViewController, you should use `initWithNibName:bundle:` instead.

Comment: added initWithNibName:@"B" bundle: nil....still same ....not displaying xib file...

Comment: when i click on the botton...it gives "Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged " message....what is this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**XIBs**

```
BViewController *bViewController = [[BViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Myview" bundle:nil];

[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController: bViewController 
                                                      animated: YES 
                                                    completion: nil];
```

**Storyboard**

```
// Here BViewController should be the name in storyboard scene then,  
BViewController *bViewController  = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"BViewController"]

[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController: bViewController 
                                                      animated: YES 
                                                    completion: nil];
```

Hope this will help.

**Note:** Try to give some meaningful names to your view controllers rather using *AViewController* and *BViewController*

Comment: Are you using xibs still?

Comment: didn't work....now this is the error ::: setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key navBar. not using navBar anywhere....

Comment: Seems you have not set controller name in file owner option in xib file. Search about that.

Comment: And for your info, xibs are now no more in use, try to migrate in storyboards if you are developing new app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80987/discussion-between-mrunal-and-anjali).

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify your nib name while presenting view like this

```
BViewController *b = [[BViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"your_nib_name" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:b animated:YES];
```