# Why am I getting a black screen when I use self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil) Xcode swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

So I'm try to set up a login func (which worked) but when I test the login, I get to the login screen and login in. Then It shows a black screen.

```
    func login(){

    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(Username.text!, password: Password.text!, completion: {

        user, error in

        if error != nil{

            print("Incorrect Username/Password")

        }
        else{

            print("Welcome")
            self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)




        }

    })

}
```

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong.
The signInWithEmail part doesn't affect the UIview.

Comment: is signInWithEmail call your completion closure on a background thread?

Comment: ^^^ I believe @FouZ has the right idea... you need to present the view controller on the main thread

Comment: Possible duplicate of [presentViewController shows black page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621619/presentviewcontroller-shows-black-page)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Storyboard name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpWhB.png) I'm new to this but the following answer worked for me

```
 let NextView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("xyzVC") as! xyzVC

 self.presentViewController(NextView, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

used the following answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30248306/6679536

again, I'm new, so maybe this will create issues in the future!
make sure you call the ViewController in storyboard the exact same name, as shown in the picture... otherwise you will get a huge error.

Comment: You should rather flag the question a duplicate instead of writing this in an answer.

Comment: sorry, its my first answer on this site, will do that next time